# Find the every nth occurrence of a string

Tags: windows, notepad++, regex, sublime-text

Despite the many similar questions, I am still confused.

```
qx|o1|md|4SAK9H7DQ876CAJ943,SJT8642H2DKT2CQ76,SQ5HKT653DAJCKT52|rh||ah|Board 1|sv|0|pg||
qx|o2|md|4SKQJ7642H9DQJ8CK8,STHAK8762D74CQJ65,SA85HQJTDAK96CT92|rh||ah|Board 2|sv|0|pg||
qx|o3|md|4ST3HAT9DAK96CA983,S76HK864D732CJT74,SAQJ82HJDQJT85CKQ|rh||ah|Board 3|sv|0|pg||
qx|o4|md|4SAQ4HT65432DAJ4CJ,SJT765HAKDT982C43,SK98HQJ9DK75CAQ92|rh||ah|Board 4|sv|0|pg||
```

In the above text, how do I find the every second occurrence of `4S`, and replace it with `3S`? (Or, in every other line, `4S` becomes `3S`.) (It is a given that the string `4S` occurs only once in every line.) I working in Sublime Text, or Notepad++ on Windows.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What happens with your search? What program are you using?

Comment: In case any Linux user appears with a similar problem: `sed '2~2 s/4S/3S/' <datafile`

Comment: @Kamil Thanks, even that will do. (via https://sed.js.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.*?4S.*?\K4S`
- Replace with: `3S`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
4S          # literally 4S, first one
.*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
4S          # literally 4S, second one
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need something like sed or awk to pull that off.
On a Bash shell in Linux I'd use sed with the following commads:

```
sed -e 'N; s/4s/3s/2' < file.txt
```

whereby `file.txt` should contain your input lines.

When started, sed will
- pull the first line into the pattern space of sed,
- `N` will pull the next (second) line into the pattern space and
- `s/4s/3s/2' will then replace the second occurrence of "4s" in the pattern space with "3s".
After that the two lines are written to the standard output and a new cycle of sed begins.

Obviously, you also can pipe the output of a previous command through that.

```
'command' | sed -e 'N; s/4s/3s/2'
```